# React Typescript custom typ with method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to define a type that contains a method according to this example?

```
export type TUserData = {
A: number,
B: number,
function isComplete():boolean{
    return ((A>0) && (B>0));
}
```

}

I want to use React's type un useContect.

```
    import {createContext, useContext} from 'react';
import {TUserData, initUserDataUser} from "./auth.api";

export type UserContextType = {
    userDataContext: IUserData
    setUserDataContext: (user: IUserData) => void;
}

export const UserDataContext = createContext<UserContextType>({
           userDataContext:initUserData, 
           setUserDataContext:userDataContext => 
              console.warn('no UserDataContext provider')});
export const useUserDataContext = () => useContext(UserDataContext);
```

Comment: You can define a functions types (parameters and return value) but I don't think you can include logic in the type itself.

Comment: You need `class` for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answers,

I want to define the type for a useContext in React. I don't think I can pass a class like an interface, can I?

Comment: Yes, you should not do this.
In createContext<YourType>({...yourInitilization}) you need a type/interface where you define your context structure. And in "YourInitialization" you will init the content of the context. It is just an object that react will throw around but no class instance.

Comment: A type does not have the body of the function.  The type is just type TUserData = { A: number; B: number; isComplete(): boolean; }.  How you *implement* that type is up to you.

Comment: OK thank you. I will solve the problem differently.